# Cannot get the output

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkunit()
    {
    if(document.getElementById("unit2").value=="CK")
    {
    document.getElementById("unittype1").innerHTML='cm';
    document.getElementById("unittype2").innerHTML='cm';
    document.getElementById("unittype3").innerHTML='cm';
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("unittype1").innerHTML='in';
    document.getElementById("unittype2").innerHTML='in';
    document.getElementById("unittype3").innerHTML='in';
    }
    }
    function validatecal(form)
    {
    if (form.vm_length.value=="" || form.vm_length.value==0) {alert('Enter Length'); form.vm_length.focus(); return false}
    if (!IsNumber(form.vm_length.value) && form.vm_length.value!="") {alert('Invalid Length'); form.vm_length.focus(); return false}
    if (form.vm_width.value=="" || form.vm_width.value==0) {alert('Enter Width'); form.vm_width.focus(); return false}
    if (!IsNumber(form.vm_width.value) && form.vm_width.value!="") {alert('Invalid Width'); form.vm_width.focus(); return false}
    if (form.vm_height.value=="" || form.vm_height.value==0) {alert('Enter Height'); form.vm_height.focus(); return false}
    if (!IsNumber(form.vm_height.value) && form.vm_height.value!="") {alert('Invalid Height'); form.vm_height.focus(); return false}
    calcVolWeight();
    return false;
    }

    function calcVolWeight() {
            var lengthValue = document.getElementById("vm_length").value;
            var widthValue = document.getElementById("vm_width").value;
            var heightValue = document.getElementById("vm_height").value;
            var weightDivisor = document.getElementById("unit2").value == "IP" ? 139 : 5000;
            var roundFactor = document.getElementById("unit2").value == "IP" ? 1 : 0.5; 
             var originalVolume = lengthValue * widthValue * heightValue;
                    // Calculate the volumetric weight
                    var calcVolWeight = roundFactor * Math.ceil(( originalVolume / weightDivisor ) / roundFactor);
                     document.getElementById("total_weight").value = parseFloat(calcVolWeight);
            }

      </script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <form name="vcalculator" id="vcalculator" method="post" onSubmit="return validatecal(this)">



               <label >Select Units :</label>
                <select name="unit2" id="unit2"  onChange="checkunit()" >      
                <option value="CK">CM/KG</option>
                <option value="IP">Inches/Pounds</option>
           </select>
             </div> 
             </div>



             <label >Enter Dimensions :</label>
             <label ">Length</label>
             <input type="text" name="vm_length"  id="vm_length"  > 
             <span id="unittype1" >cm</span>




             <label ">Width</label>
             <input type="text" name="vm_width" id="vm_width"  /> 
             <span id="unittype2" >cm</span>



             <label ">Height</label>
             <input type="text" name="vm_height" id="vm_height"  />  
             <span id="unittype3" >cm</span>


              <label >Dimensional Weight :</label>
              <input type="text"disabled="disabled"name="total_weight" id="total_weight"  >
              <input type="submit" value="Calculate"  name="Submit"/>&nbsp;
              <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Submit2" />

            </form> 
       </body>
</html>
```

I want the code to get the output, trying to calculate the Dimensional Weight (L x W x H / 5000), please can some one help me?

After entering the length, width, height values i am unable to get the dimensional weight.

Comment: create a fiddle please .. that will be helpful.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I want to know exact error please can you correct it out

Comment: After submitting the value is not getting in to it                                  <input type="text"disabled="disabled"name="total_weight"id="total_weight" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using IsNumber() which is not a native function. Try this code

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function checkunit()
  {
   if(document.getElementById("unit2").value=="CK")
   {
    document.getElementById("unittype1").innerHTML='cm';
    document.getElementById("unittype2").innerHTML='cm';
    document.getElementById("unittype3").innerHTML='cm';
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("unittype1").innerHTML='in';
    document.getElementById("unittype2").innerHTML='in';
    document.getElementById("unittype3").innerHTML='in';
   }
  }

  function validatecal(form)
  {
   debugger;
   if (form.vm_length.value=="" 
    || form.vm_length.value==0) {
    alert('Enter Length');
    form.vm_length.focus();

    return false
   }
   
   if (isNaN(form.vm_length.value)
    && form.vm_length.value!="") {
    alert('Invalid Length');
    form.vm_length.focus();
   
    return false
   }
   
   if (form.vm_width.value=="" 
    || form.vm_width.value==0) {
    alert('Enter Width');
    form.vm_width.focus();

    return false
   }

   if (isNaN(form.vm_width.value) 
    && form.vm_width.value!="") {
    alert('Invalid Width');
    form.vm_width.focus();

    return false
   }
   
   if (form.vm_height.value=="" 
    || form.vm_height.value==0) {
    alert('Enter Height');
    form.vm_height.focus();

    return false;
   }
   if (isNaN(form.vm_height.value)
    && form.vm_height.value!="") {
    alert('Invalid Height');
    form.vm_height.focus();

    return false
   }
   calcVolWeight();
   return false;
  }

  function calcVolWeight() {
   var lengthValue = document.getElementById("vm_length").value;
   var widthValue = document.getElementById("vm_width").value;
   var heightValue = document.getElementById("vm_height").value;
   var weightDivisor = document.getElementById("unit2").value == "IP" ? 139 : 5000;
   var roundFactor = document.getElementById("unit2").value == "IP" ? 1 : 0.5;
   var originalVolume = lengthValue * widthValue * heightValue;
   // Calculate the volumetric weight
   var calcVolWeight = roundFactor * Math.ceil(( originalVolume / weightDivisor ) / roundFactor);
   document.getElementById("total_weight").value = parseFloat(calcVolWeight);
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="vcalculator" id="vcalculator" method="post" onSubmit="return validatecal(this)">
   <label >Select Units :</label>
   <select name="unit2" id="unit2"  onChange="checkunit()" >
    <option value="CK">CM/KG</option>
    <option value="IP">Inches/Pounds</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <label >Enter Dimensions :</label>
 <label>Length</label>
 <input type="text" name="vm_length"  id="vm_length"  >
 <span id="unittype1" >cm</span>
 <label ">Width</label>
 <input type="text" name="vm_width" id="vm_width"  />
 <span id="unittype2" >cm</span>
 <label ">Height</label>
 <input type="text" name="vm_height" id="vm_height"  />
 <span id="unittype3" >cm</span>
 <label >Dimensional Weight :</label>
 <input type="text"disabled="disabled"name="total_weight" id="total_weight"  >
 <input type="submit" value="Calculate"  name="Submit"/>&nbsp;
 <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Submit2" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, it was so helpfull for me